# How does JVM interpret memory arguments?

Tags: java

I have a doubt around the -Xms and other memory argument parameters. Since JVM is a C/C++ implemented program so whenever we try to pass on memory arguments at the runtime does it internally use Malloc/Calloc to assign memory to our Java program ?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to know this? Or, what difference would it make if you knew the answer? Which of the many JVM implementations do you mean?

Comment: I wanted to know the implementation for Hotspot JVM . This will equip be with a better understanding of how JVM works internally. Just to increase my knowledge base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out how the HotSpot JVM implements the specification, you can have a look at the actual code.

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp

Look for `size_t max_heap` or `match_option(option, "-Xmx"` and follow the code from there.

Since HotSpot is written in C++, it will probably not use `malloc/calloc`, but `new/delete`, but even more probably some kind of `mmap`.